# In shell, how to extract substring from a complete file path

Tags: bash, shell

If I have the variables like:

```
baseFolder="/a/b/c/"
completeFilePath="a/b/c/x/y/z.txt"
```

How to extract the substring from `completeFilePath` and get the output as:

```
x/y/z.txt
```

`baseFolder` directory depth may be more or less

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bash parameter expansion:

```sh
baseFolder="/a/b/c/"
completeFilePath="/a/b/c/x/y/z.txt"

echo "${completeFilePath#$baseFilePath}"
```

Refer: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal

Comment: You don't need echo inside echo. This is enough: `echo "${completeFilePath#$baseFilePath}"`

Answer (score 3):

Try to solve this with `awk`

```
$ baseFolder="/a/b/c/"
$ completeFilePath="a/b/c/x/y/z.txt"

$ echo $completeFilePath| awk -v a=$baseFolder '{len=length(a)}{print substr($0,len)}'
x/y/z.txt
```

Brief explanation:

1. `len=length(a)`: get the length of `$baseFolder`
2. `substr($0,len)`: print the substring of `$completeFilePath` starting from position `len`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way using bash parameter expansion:

```
b="a/b/c/d/"
p="a/b/c/d/x/y/z.txt"

echo "${p/${b}/}"
```

The substitution takes the base folder as the pattern and replaces it with nothing (removing it).